# How to compare objects in a python list based on their relative list position?

Tags: python, list, text

I have some text data that I am trying to clean. One of the undesired features of this data are duplicate tokens separated by a specific marker. I am trying to find a way to (1) identify that marker in the text, and (2) remove one of the duplicates.

Toy Example:

```
word_list = ['this','is','a','!!','a','list','I','want','to','clean']
```

Here, there are two duplicate 'a' tokens separated by a marker '!!'. I am trying to find the most effective way to iterate over the list with the following

```
#pseudo
for word in word_list
    if word == "!!":
        if word[at word-1] == word[at word+1]  # compare words either side of the "!!" marker
            del word[at word+1]                # removing the duplicate
            del word                           # removing the "!!" marker


output = ['this','is','a','list','I','want','to','clean']
```

I have tried several approaches involving the `enumerate` function but cannot seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your logic and the `enumerate` function:

```
word_list = ['this','is','a','!!','a','list','I','want','to','clean']

for i, word in enumerate(word_list):
    if word == "!!":
        if word_list[i-1] == word_list[i+1]:
            word_list[i+1] = ""
            word_list[i] = ""

print ([x for x in word_list if x])
```

Output:

```
['this', 'is', 'a', 'list', 'I', 'want', 'to', 'clean']
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
word_list = ['this', 'is', 'a', '!!', 'a', 'list', 'I', 'want', 'to', 'clean']

for i, word in enumerate(word_list):
    if word == "!!":
        if word_list[i-1] == word_list[i+1]:  # checking if they are duplicates
            del word_list[i+1]  # removing the duplicate
            del word_list[i]  # removing the marker
```

Answer (score 0):

I your separator is always '!!" the following should work:

```
result=[]

for i in range(len(word_list)-2):
    if not (word_list[i]=='!!' or (word_list[i+1]=='!!' and  word_list[i+2]==word_list[i])):
       result.append(word_list[i])
if word_list[-2]!='!!':
    result.append(word_list[-2])
if word_list[-1]!='!!':
    result.append(word_list[-1])

print(result)
#['this', 'is', 'a', 'list', 'I', 'want', 'to', 'clean']
```

Answer (score -1):

Somthing along the following lines would work:

```
word_list = ['this','is','a','!!','a','list','I','want','to','clean']

i, marker, output = 0, "!!", []

while i < len(word_list):
    x = word_list[i]
    output.append(x)
    if word_list[i+1:i+3] == [marker, x]:
        i += 3
    else:
        i += 1

output
# ['this', 'is', 'a', 'list', 'I', 'want', 'to', 'clean']
```

And if you want to mutate the original list object:

```
word_list[:] = output
```